# scrollIntoView works only once when followed by console.log

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Apparently when scrollIntoView works only once when followed by console.log. As you can see in the below demo, once you remove the console.log it will scroll down and up with no problems. But with console.log it will work just the first time. Can someone explain to me please this weird behavior ?

```js
function scr () {
document.querySelector('#t1').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth",block: 'start',inline: "start"});


}

function scr1 () {
document.querySelector('#t4').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth",block: 'start',inline: "start"});

console.log("remove this console.log and it will work again");

}
```

```css
.flex-container > div {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;">
<button onclick="scr()" >scroll up</button>
<button onclick="scr1()">scroll down</button>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
<div id="t1">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="t2">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="t3">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="t4">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce that issue, I can see that you're missing a semicolon (;) after the `console.log`, perhaps your browser has parsing issue after running it, still seems like a farfetched cause.

Comment: You're right I only reproduce this in chrome 86.0.4240.75 it does work however with firefox

Comment: BTW `scrollIntoView` is kind of new and not supported at all in Safari, so I don't use that at all yet. I use other methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView `Experimental. Expect behavior to change in the future.`

Comment: No worries I was targeting a best effort approach using scrollIntoView options

Comment: I'll leave this post open as I sent this url to chrome support.

Comment: Bug confirmed on linux Chrome 111.0.5563.146 (Official Build) (64-bit). Weird one!

Answer (score 1):

This definitely seems like a Chrome bug, but a workaround seems to be putting the call in a setTimeout, even 10ms later works for me. This also fixes the same bug with window.scrollTo().

```js
function scr () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('#t1').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth",block: 'start',inline: "start"});
  }, 10);
}

function scr1 () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('#t4').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth",block: 'start',inline: "start"});
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
.flex-container > div {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;">
<button onclick="scr()" >scroll up</button>
<button onclick="scr1()">scroll down</button>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
<div id="t1">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="t2">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="t3">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="t4">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>
```